C++ std::map emplace_hint - long processing time when increasing the iterator
I am trying to understand the sample code at the emplace_hint() documentation: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace_hint
Especially the following function:
std::size_t map_emplace_hint_closest()
{
    std::map<int, char> map;
    auto it = map.begin();
    for (int i = 0; i < n_operations; ++i)
        it = map.emplace_hint(it, i, 'e');
    return map.size();
}

Up to my understanding, here the iterator that is offered to the emplace_hint(), is not exactly "the one before which the new element should be inserted", but is iterator to the "previously inserted element, AFTER which new insert will be made". But it seems the iterator is still "close enough" to the correct one, so this function runs fast. I tried running the code on the abovementioned website and with slightly more than 1M members inserted (why such weird number 1005000 in the example?), the execution time was something like 83 ms, which was even better than in function map_emplace_hint(), where the iterator is just set to map.end() after each insertion.
Just out of curiosity, I thought that what would the execution time be if I used the returned iterator value in map_emplace_hint_closest(), but would increase it to match the next element insertion place exactly:
    for (int i = 0; i < n_operations; ++i)
    {
        it = map.emplace_hint(it, i, 'e');
        ++it;
    }

And as a big surprise, the execution time ended up being over 300 ms - similar as using emplace() without any hint at all. In my understanding, the iterator increase operation should not be an expensive one (at least not comparable to inserting into a large map without any hint at all), so what is the problem here? Is my hint in the latest loop wrong?
I also tried what happens if I just increase the iterator, without using the emplace_hint() return value:
    for (int i = 0; i < n_operations; ++i)
    {
        map.emplace_hint(it, i, 'e');
        ++it;
    }

And this made the function fast again - 86 ms. So the problem with long execution time seems to be related to using the returned iterator and then increasing it.
All my tests were carried out on cppreference website with default options (GCC13.1 (C++23)).
Note that I am asking this question to know what is wrong in my logic, NOT that I would want to run exactly that code in my project. I would like to know the overall reason, WHY correcting the iterator I have to point to the exact position of next emplace is so expensive?
Thank you in advance.

Two observations: If you increment the iterator but never use the result, the compiler will probably just remove that code, making any benchmark on it unreliable. Two: Since you emplace integers of increasing value, ++it will always be equal to map.end() with the only difference that the compiler does not know that and you still incur the extra cost of iterating from one entry to the next, causing an extra loop-carried dependency.

@Homer512 About your first observation: in all of my examples, the iterator that is assigned or incremented, is actually later used - as a parameter to the next emplace_hint() call.

That was pointed at your line I also tried what happens if I just increase the iterator, without using the emplace_hint() return value but I misunderstood your code. In that part, you increment an iterator that was originally the end() iterator (since you start with an empty map so it = map.begin() is the same as map.end(). I'm not sure that's even valid behavior.

When you trace that operation through the GCC STL code, you will find the relevant function _M_get_insert_hint_unique_pos in bits/stl_tree.h. The code is cryptic but it's not hard to see that it works with hint being both before and after the insertion point. But it does not consider any hints further away. This contradicts the GCC documentation that claims only hints after the insertion point are used.
